# '&' binding does not seems to be working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I cannot understand what is wrong with this simple '&' binding. I define a function on component's controller, a binding, and I attach that binding to that function. However the link does not work.

Example:

DOM:

```
<mycomp f='$ctrl.myfunc()'></mycomp>
```

JS:

```
app.component('mycomp', {
    bindings: {
        f: '&'
    },
    controller: function(){
        ctrl = this;

        ctrl.myfunc = function() {
            console.log('ciao'); 
        };

        ctrl.$postLink = function() {
            ctrl.f();
            console.log(ctrl.f.toString()); // (*)
        };
    }
});
```

When I execute this, function myfunc never gets executed and in the log the output of (*) is:

```
function (b){return H(a,b)}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: When using `&` binding, angularjs evaluates this expression `'$ctrl.myfunc()'` on the parent scope, so this means that `$ctrl.myfunc()` should be defined in your parent `component`/`controller`.

Comment: I understand, you're right. I missed that part on the docs.

Comment: It is good you were able to resolve the issue :)

Comment: However is there a way to accomplish what I was trying to do? i.e. to bind a function to an attribute, being the function defined on the very same controller of the element?

Comment: Why would you need it in the attribute (as it is defined in the same controller, you can call it inside of it without bindings and any other magic)? Can you provide any usage test case, when it could have any sense? :)

Comment: Perhaps this is a bad design, however: I have this general component, with its template and a controller which run some code; then, inside the controller, I have defined several functions myfunc1, myfunc2, myfunc3, ...; I place many of these components on the DOM, and I'd like to configure each of them specifying in an attribute which function that specific instance of the component should run. For instance <mycomp f="myfunc1"></mycomp><mycomp f="myfunc2"></mycomp>, so when the controller calls the generic function f, only the configured function gets executed for each component. Sounds weird?

Comment: So maybe better to pass `@` for example lets say `componentType`, a then inside your generic function check this binding's value and return call corresponding method, something like this could work: `ctrl.f = function () {
            switch (ctrl.componentType){
                case 'type1':
                    return ctrl.myfunc1();
                    break;
                case 'type2':
                    return ctrl.myfunc2();
                    break;
                default: return angular.noop(); break;
            }
        };` (so called factory noob-implementation).